# How do you find the end of a line using RegExp in VBA (Microsoft Word)?

Tags: regex, vba, ms-word, newline, wildcard

I'm attempting to use regular expressions to find a specific substring and everything after it until the next line.  For example:

```
These are numbers: one, two, three
These are colors: yellow, blue, green
```

I want to find the string "numbers: one, two, three", and I've used the following pattern:

```
Public Sub TEST()
        
    Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    regex.Global = True
    
    For Each Match In findRegEx(ActiveDocument.Range, "numbers: .*")
        Debug.Print Match.Value
    Next
End Sub
```

Every explanation of the 'wildcard' metacharacter I've found leads me to believe it will locate every character *except* for newline characters, but this pattern also returns the second line instead of just the first.  I'm not sure if I'm misunderstanding the nature of the wildcard or of newlines in Word.

Comment: Please include the code you are using to run this regex, not just the regex itself.

Comment: maybe use `numbers: .*\r` for your regex?

Comment: I tried ```\r```, it did not work, either.

Comment: Is the end of the line actually a carriage return or something else?

Comment: That's sort of the question, I don't know what exactly denotes the end of a line.  I've tried ```\r```, ```\n```, ```vbCr```, ```vbNewline```, and ```Chr(13)```, and none of them produce the desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ask the regular expression to **not** match the end-of-line character.

So replace `"numbers: .*"` with `"numbers: [^\n]*"` which can be read as "match strings starting with 'numbers: ' and any non-end-of-line character".

If your string uses other end-of-line characters , you will have to adjust the \n to one or a combination , probably of the common cases \n \r.

Don't try to use `vbCr`,`vbNewLine` or `Chr(13)` as part the pattern definition - these are literals. The regular expression syntax expects special symbols to indicate these values.

---

Note you have a space after the colon ':'.

Comment: This worked!  Almost.  the only  end-of-line character I can make work is Chr(13):

```"numbers: [^] & Chr(13) & "]*"```  This works as intended.  Thank you!

Comment: Thanks Dominic - I'll adjust the answer once I check some details.